# How to prevent WordPress scaling large images down

Tags: images, media-library

I've tried the following code in the active child theme's functions.php to prevent the large digital print JPGs from being scaled down, but it didn't succeed:

```
function remove_all_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
            remove_image_size( $size );
    }
}
 
add_action('init', 'remove_all_image_sizes');
```

Can you help me 'turn off' WordPress scaling down large images please?

Help appreciated.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`big_image_size_threshold` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/big_image_size_threshold/) - my post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/370769) might also help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? WP always keeps the oriiginal size image file under the image size name `full`

Comment: Just open media from dashboard settings and remove the thumbnail, Medium-sized & large size. Wordpress will stop resizing the uploaded pictures.